# Accessing nested object with pug, json, htmlwebpackplugin

Tags: html-webpack-plugin, pug-loader

I seem to be having an issue accessing a value from a mixin when trying to use bracket notation. I have the following setup:

```
// in webpack plugins
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: true,
            template: './assets/template/about.pug',
            filename: 'about-us.html',
            inject: true,
            page: 'about',
            locals: require('./assets/data.json'),
            chunks: ['about']
        }),
```

The json

```
// data.json (snippet)
{
    "pages" : {
        "about" : {"title" : "About Us","metaDesc" : ""},
    }
}
```

Pug mixin

```
mixin pageTitle(thePage)
    title= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.locals.pages[thePage].title
```

Using pug mixin

```
+pageTitle(htmlWebpackPlugin.options.page)
```

I get an error `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined.`

If I change that to `htmlWebpackPlugin.options.locals.pages.about.title` it will parse just fine.

If I change that to `htmlWebpackPlugin.options.locals.pages[thePage]` it will return `[object Object]` but I can't access any properties.

If I change that to `htmlWebpackPlugin.options.page` or just use `thePage` then "about" will be rendered.

I've done a typeof to check if it's a string. It is. I've tried putting it into a variable first. Same issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need notation in brackets? What is the purpose of this?
This record works `title = thePage.pages.about['title']`

---

I prefer the following entry ;)
In the file `about.pug`, make an entry at the very top.

```
block variables
- var path = self.htmlWebpackPlugin.options
```

You pass on to the function

```
// locals is the path to your json file
+pageTitle(path.locals)
```

Mixin should look like this

```
mixin pageTile(thePage)
  title = thePage.pages.about.title
```

Here you have the whole example in addition with generating multiple subpages with `pug-loader` → [photoBlog](https://github.com/tomik23/photoBlog/blob/master/sources/templates/index.pug#L2)